# Overlay and container problems

Tags: html, css

if anyone sees this post and want to help me, I would be very happy. So I have a problem with some codes as I do not know how to add them in the div style format.

The codes are:

- . overlay opacity:0 and
- .container:hover .overlay opacity:1

I really do not know how to add them in the div style section.

[code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayksn.png)

But nothing was happening, and the fade was not there anymore like before.
And if I put in Overlay both opacitys (ex: opacity: 0; and opacity: 1;) in the div style,... yeah did not do well.

[code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSR2E.png)

So please if anyone can help me, please. And hopefully I did wrote it so that everyone can understand it. :)

Comment: You have to explain a bit more carefully what you need. at this point i am just guessing.
you can do something like `div:hover { opacity: 1; }` .

Comment: Provide minimum reproducible code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is some working html/css code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .overlay {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .overlay:hover {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" style="text-align: center; margin: 0 
calc(50vw - 115px); display: inline-block; z-index: -1; 
position: static;">
    <h1>Hover over me!</h1>
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image- 
vector/smile-icon-vector-face-emoticon-260nw-1721368459.jpg" width="200" height="190" style="object-fit: cover;" />
  </div>
  <div class="overlay" style="width: 250px; height: 100%; 
background-color: gainsboro; z-index: 1; top:0; left:0; 
display: block; position: fixed; margin: 0 calc(50vw - 
125px);">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

the second code will not work because its not possible to use a psuedo class in the class name. though you can use html dom Events and a some javescript to do it.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container" style="text-align: center; margin: 0 
calc(50vw - 115px); display: inline-block; z-index: -1; 
position: static;">
    <h1>Hover over me!</h1>
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image- 
vector/smile-icon-vector-face-emoticon-260nw-1721368459.jpg" 
width="200" height="190" style="object-fit: cover;" />
  </div>
  <div class="overlay" onmouseover="this.style.opacity = 
'0.5';" onmouseout="this.style.opacity = '0';" style="width: 
250px; height: 100%; background-color: gainsboro; opacity: 0; 
z-index: 1; top:0; left:0; display: block; position: fixed; 
margin: 0 calc(50vw - 125px);">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```